# Problem with creating wifi-hotspot with with hostapd and dnsmasq

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq, pop-os, hostapd, systemd-resolved

### OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (64 bit)

I am trying to create an access point on my laptop and connect my android phone to it. My phone connects, shows **Obtaining IP Address**, and disconnects immediately. I think this is an issue with DHCP but I am not sure. I mainly followed [this](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/monitoring-android-traffic-wireshark) blog. The details are below:

I have 3 files in my project root directory. Namely **makeWAP.sh**, **hostapd.conf** and **dnsmasq.conf**. I am pasting the files below:

### makeWAP.sh

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                    
export DEV_IN=wlp3s0;
export DEV_OUT=enp2s0;
export DNS_SERV=10.0.0.1;
export DNS_PORT=3000;
echo "Bringing up $DEV_IN"
#This address/mask should match how you configured dnsmasq
ifconfig $DEV_IN up $DNS_SERV netmask 255.255.255.0

echo "Starting dnsmasq"
dnsmasq --resolv-file=/home/abuobaidazishan/DevProjects/makeWAP/dnsmasq.conf

echo "Configuring iptables"
#Clear everything in iptables                                                   
iptables -Z;
iptables -F;
iptables -X;

#Turn on iptables NAT, forwarding, and enable 
#forwarding in the kernel

iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface $DEV_OUT -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface $DEV_IN -j ACCEPT
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

echo "Starting hostapd"
hostapd /home/abuobaidazishan/DevProjects/makeWAP/hostapd.conf
```

### dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=wlp3s0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.3,10.0.0.20,12h
port=3000
```

### hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlp3s0
driver=nl80211
ssid=WatchingU
channel=1
```

#### This is the output of `sh makeWAP.sh` as root:

```
Bringing up wlp3s0
Starting dnsmasq
Configuring iptables
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
Starting hostapd
wlp3s0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlp3s0: AP-ENABLED 
wlp3s0: STA 26:b3:4d:c1:3b:49 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlp3s0: STA 26:b3:4d:c1:3b:49 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlp3s0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 26:b3:4d:c1:3b:49
wlp3s0: STA 26:b3:4d:c1:3b:49 RADIUS: starting accounting session 922EA81DDF566B77
wlp3s0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 26:b3:4d:c1:3b:49
```

##### These are consecutive screenshots of my phone trying to stay connected:

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKEsR.png) [pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr1bC.png)

Now you might be asking, why I changed the default port of DNS queries to 3000 when it should be 53. Well, when I ran `netstat -tulnp` as root, I got this:

```
root@pop-os:/home/abuobaidazishan# netstat -tulnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      835/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           835/systemd-resolve
```

As you can see the systemd-resolv is already using it. So the commands of dnsmasq fail stating that the port is already being used.

Below is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 60:18:95:2f:73:2b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3728  bytes 962026 (962.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3728  bytes 962026 (962.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::7d6d:7224:9348:b5d6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 90:0f:0c:1c:ad:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 329808  bytes 320182341 (320.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 139852  bytes 18440551 (18.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It would be really helpful if you told me ***why*** this is happening. I have been googling and everyone seems to have a slightly different approach. For which, I am not sure which one to follow. Also, from my question, I think you are pretty sure that I am a noob. Therefore, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try these tricks:

1. disable NetworkManager

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager
   ```
2. try set the "wpa_pairwise". e.g.: in /etc/hostapd.conf , add this line

   ```
   wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
   ```
3. Try different Linux kernel version. In my case the solution only works in "some" of the kernel versions, not the "latest" version.
4. Or, try `wpa_passphrase` instead of the `wpa_psk` in the `/etc/hostapd.conf`.

In my case, this fixed the issue. It feels like a bug in the hostapd related to the wifi PSK password authentication, see [this related issue](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/issues/695).